# How can I parse only part of an HTML file and ignore the rest?

Tags: perl, html-parsing

In each of 5,000 HTML files I have to get only one line of text, which is line 999. How can I tell the HTML::Parser that I only have to get line 999?

```
</p><h1>dataset 1:</h1>

&nbsp;<table border="0" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"  leftmargin="15" topmargin="5"><tr>  
<td><strong>name:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td width=500> myname one         </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>type:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td width=500>       type_one  (04313488)        </td></tr><tr>
<td><strong>aresss:</strong>&nbsp;</td><td>Friedrichstr. 70,&nbsp;73430&nbsp;Madrid</td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>adresse_two:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>          no_value        </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>telefone:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>         0000736111/680040        </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>Fax:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>          0000736111/680040        </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>E-Mail:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>       Keine Angabe        </td></tr><tr>      
<td><strong>Internet:</strong>&nbsp;</td><td><a href="http://www.mysite.es" target="_blank">www.mysite.es</a><br></td></tr><tr> <td><strong>the office:</strong>&nbsp;</td>   
<td><a href="http://www.mysite_two" target="_blank">mysite_two </a><br></td></tr><tr> 
<td><strong>:</strong>&nbsp;</td><td> no_value </td></tr><tr> 
<td><strong>officer:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td> no_value        </td>  </td></tr><tr>
<td><strong>employees:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td> 259        </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>offices:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>     8        </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>worker:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>     no_value        </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>country:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>    contryname        </td></tr><tr>  
<td><strong>the_council:</strong>&nbsp;</td>  <td>
```

Well, the question is, is it possible to do the search in the 5000 files with this attribute: That the line 999 is of interest. In other words, can I tell the HTML-parser that it has to look (and extract) exactly line 999?

---

Hello dear RedGritty Brick - i have little experience with HTML :: TokeParser

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;

#use real file name here
open(my $fh, "<", "file.html") or die $!;

$tree->parse_file($fh);

my ($name) = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});

print $name->as_text;
```

BTW; **RedGrittyBrick:** See one of the example sites: http://www.kultusportal-bw.de/servlet/PB/menu/1188427/index.html?COMPLETEHREF=http://www.kultus-bw.de/did_abfrage/detail.php?id=04313488
in the grey shadowed  block you see the wanted information: 17 lines that are wanted. Note - i have 5000 different HTML-files - that all are structured in the very same way!

That means i would be happy to have a template that can be runned with HTML::TokeParser::Simple and DBI.

love to get hints

Comment: possible duplicate of [xpather running against HTML-files: defining the paths to prepare a parser-job run Perl's HTML::TokePaser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949091/xpather-running-against-html-files-defining-the-paths-to-prepare-a-parser-job-ru)

Comment: Which line of that HTML is the one you want to extract, or is that all on one line?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the 999th line or the 999th table row?

The former might be

```
perl -ne 'print if $. == 999' /path/to/*.dat
```

The latter would involve an HTML parser and some selection logic. A Sax parser might be better for fast processing of a large number of files. It probably depends which version of HTML is used and whether it is "well-formed".

Perl has many XML and HTML parsers - did you have any particular module in mind?

---

EDIT:

Your problem seems to be your XPath expression. The actual HTML is much more complex than
your XPath suggests. The following expression works better

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

#
# replace this with a loop over 5000 existing files
#
my $url = 'http://www.kultusportal-bw.de/'.
          'servlet/PB/menu/1188427/index.html'.
          '?COMPLETEHREF='.
          'http://www.kultus-bw.de/'.
          'did_abfrage/detail.php?id=04313488';
my $html = get $url;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new();
#
# within the loop process the html like this
#
$tree->parse($html);
$tree->eof;
print $tree->findvalue('//table[@bgcolor]/tr[1]');
```

Try cutting the above and pasting into a file then running it with Perl.

Comment: use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;

#use real file name here
open(my $fh, "<", "file.html") or die $!;

$tree->parse_file($fh);

my ($name) = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});

print $name->as_text;

the example sites: 
http://www.kultusportal-bw.de/servlet/PB/menu/1188427/index.html?COMPLETEHREF=http://www.kultus-bw.de/did_abfrage/detail.php?id=04313488
in the grey shadowed  block you see the wanted information: 17 lines that are wanted. Note - i have 5000 HTML-files -

Comment: Hello RedGrittyBrick: Guess that i now understand your code. You did the  trick with the color! YOu solved the issue with working with the grey shadowed color! Is this true!? GREAT Job! I am overwhelmed. Congrats. Greetings Martin

Comment: If you're going to show code, please update your question. Forcing people to read code in comments is cruel.

Comment: hello brian d foy - thx for the posting. I agree. Being a novice i have to learn alot! - greetings

Comment: @Martin, yes - the HTML has several tables, therefore specify a table attribute that uniquely identifies which table you are interested in. I found it worth reading the W3C tutorials on XPath expressions.