# How can I extract the contents of a specific table from HTML source using Perl?

Tags: perl, html-parsing, html-table

I have to parse 5000 files - which look pretty identical.

I like using [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple) and [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI) in order to do the parsing job and store the results.

I have little experience with `HTML::TokeParser::Simple` but this task goes over
my head. Note: i also have had a look at the ideas - that seems to be also an appropiate way. But at the moment i have issues to get the correspodending xpath-expressions: I tried to determine the corresponding xpath-expressions that needs to be filled in the Perl-programme.

This is what I have right now:

```
use strict;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;

#use real file name here
open(my $fh, "<", "file.html") or die $!;

$tree->parse_file($fh);

my ($name)       = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($type)       = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($adress)     = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($adress_two) = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($telephone)  = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($fax)    = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($internet)   = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($officer)    = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($employees)  = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($offices)    = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($worker)     = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($country)    = $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});
my ($the_council)= $tree->findnodes(qq{/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]});


print $name->as_text;
print $type->as_text;
print $adress->as_text;
print $adress_two->as_text;
print $telephone->as_text;
print $fax->as_text;
print $internet->as_text;
print $officer->as_text;
print $employees->as_text;
print $offices->as_text;
print $worker->as_text;
print $country->as_text;
print $the_council->as_text;
```

is this all right ?  Note - i w ant to store this in a database.

BTW: See one of the example sites:

http://www.kultusportal-bw.de/servlet/PB/menu/1188427/index.html?COMPLETEHREF=http://www.kultus-bw.de/did_abfrage/detail.php?id=04313488

in the grey shadowed  block you see the wanted information: 17 lines that are wanted. Note - i have 5000 different HTML-files - that all are structured in the very same way!

That means i would be happy to have a template that can be runned with HTML::TokeParser::Simple and DBI.

Can i make use of the above mentioned code... or do i have to change it.

Love to hear from you! That would be great!!

Comment: FYI: I have tried to edit your question, but I cannot make sense of the title. Please try to come up with something descriptive.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3946874/100754

Answer (score 3):

Use some [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTableExtract) magic:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use YAML;

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( attribs => {
    border => 0,
    bgcolor => '#EFEFEF',
    leftmargin => 15,
    topmargin => 5,
});

$te->parse_file('kultus-bw.html');
my ($table) = $te->tables;

for my $row ( $table->rows ) {
    cleanup(@$row);
    print "@$row\n";
}

sub cleanup {
    for ( @_ ) {
        s/\s+//;
        s/[\xa0 ]+\z//;
        s/\s+/ /g;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Schul-/Behördenname: Abendgymnasium Ostwürttemberg
Schulart: Privatschule (04313488)
Hausadressse: Friedrichstr.70, 73430 Aalen
Postfachadresse: Keine Angabe
Telefon: 07361/680040
Fax: 07361/680040
E-Mail: Keine Angabe
Internet: www.abendgymnasium-ostwuerttemberg.de 
ÜbergeordneteDienststelle: Regierungspräsidium Stuttgart Abteilung 7 Schule und Bildung 
Schulleitung: Keine Angabe
Stellv.Schulleitung: Keine Angabe
AnzahlSchüler: 259
AnzahlKlassen: 8
AnzahlLehrer: Keine Angabe
Kreis: Ostalbkreis
Schulträger: <Verband/Verein> (Verband/Verein)
```

Of course, I saved a local copy of the page before running the script.

Comment: Hello Sinan Ünür, that is great. You did more than expected. I am very happy. This is exactly what i want to have as result. I am overwhelmed. This code you suggest does the whole trick!

Comment: Again Sinan Ünur, I am excited. I have to understand the code. You get great outputs. And i love to understand this great code - that is able to give this ouptut! GREAT Job. - I come back later this day. Now i have leave the house for two hours. But sure thing i come back! Many many thanks again! Greetings martin

Comment: again me - tried to correct the thread-title. The system denied that since i am a new user. Martin

Comment: @martin Post the correct title as a comment to your question and someone else will fix it for you. Also, the documentation for `HTML::TableExtract` is available. It does what it says it does: Extracts specific tables from HTML source code. And it does that *really* well.