# Beautiful Soup [Python] and the extracting of text in a table

Tags: php, python

i am new to Python and to Beatiful Soup also! I heard about BS. It is told to be a great tool to parse and extract content. So here i am...:

I want to take the content of the first td of a table in a html
document. For example, i have this table

```
<table class="bp_ergebnis_tab_info">
    <tr>
            <td>
                     This is a sample text
            </td>

            <td>
                     This is the second sample text
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can i use beautifulsoup to take the text "This is a sample text"?
I use soup.findAll('table' ,attrs={'class':'bp_ergebnis_tab_info'}) to get
the whole table.

Thanks... or should i try to get  the whole stuff with Perl ... which i am not so familiar with. Another soltion would be a regex in PHP.

See the target  [1]: http://www.schulministerium.nrw.de/BP/SchuleSuchen?action=799.601437941842&SchulAdresseMapDO=142323

Note; since the html is a  bit invalid - i think that we have to do some cleaning. That can cause a lot of PHP code - since we want to solve the job in PHP. Perl would be a good solution too.

Many thanks for some hints and ideas for a starting point
zero

Comment: Well, clearly, you have failed to get much out of your Perl questions, so I am not even sure why this question is tagged with Perl. Also, don't create new accounts every few weeks: Create one and stick with it. @zero knows what I am talking about. Others can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/users/477580/thebutcher and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3991571/100754 and questions linked from there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First find the table (as you are doing). Using `find` rather than `findall` returns the first item in the list (rather than returning a list of all finds - in which case we'd have to add an extra `[0]` to take the first element of the list):

```
table = soup.find('table' ,attrs={'class':'bp_ergebnis_tab_info'})
```

Then use `find` again to find the first `td`:

```
first_td = table.find('td')
```

Then use `renderContents()` to extract the textual contents:

```
text = first_td.renderContents()
```

... and the job is done (though you may also want to use `strip()` to remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
trimmed_text = text.strip()
```

This should give:

```
>>> print trimmed_text
This is a sample text
>>>
```

as desired.

Comment: Hello psmears, many many thanks for the answer. You encourage me to  use Beautiful soup! Your hints were very very lucent and concise. Many thanks for this great asset of "Learing-a-new-technique". I am happy. Greetings Zero

Comment: Can you search with `find()` for textual contents instead of `text=`?

Comment: How do you find the seocnd td?

Comment: @TheLaggyTablet: Use `findall` then subscript the result with `[1]`.

Answer (score 10):

**Use "text" to get text between "td"**

1) First read table DOM using tag or ID

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, "html.parser")
htnm_migration_table = soup.find("table", {'id':'htnm_migration_table'})
```

2) Read tbody

```
tbody = htnm_migration_table.find('tbody')
```

3) Read all tr from tbody tag

```
trs = tbody.find_all('tr')
```

4) get all tds using tr

```
for tr in trs:
      tds = tr.find_all('td')
      for td in tds:
      print(td.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find Beautiful Soup very efficient tool so keep learning it :-) It is able to parse a page with invalid markup so it should be able to handle the page you refer. You may want to use command `BeautifulSoup(html).prettify()` command if you want to get a valid reformatted page source with valid markup.

As for your question, the result of your first `soup.findAll(...)` command is also a Beautiful Soup object and you can make a second search in it, like this:

```
table_soup = soup.findAll('table' ,attrs={'class':'bp_ergebnis_tab_info'})
your_sample_text = table_soup.find("td").renderContents().strip()

print your_sample_text
```

Comment: Hello Martin - many many thanks for the great hints. I am very happy about your posting: You encourage me to learn Beautiful Soup! I will do! As for the code. I will apply the Code to the above mentioned target-url. I come back and report all my findings. Again - many thanks for your help! This is a great learning-asset for me! Greetings to you (and to the whole community)