# Use beautiful soup to find elements by textual contents, not text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Similar to `.renderContents` here, I want to search by that value: [Beautiful Soup [Python] and the extracting of text in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416013/beautiful-soup-python-and-the-extracting-of-text-in-a-table)

Sample HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <td>
                     This is garbage
            </td>
            <td>
            <td class="thead" style="font-weight:normal">       
                <!-- status icon and date -->
                <a name="post1"><img class="inlineimg" src="img.gif" alt="Old" border="0" title="Old"></a>
                19-11-2010, 04:25 PM

                <!-- / status icon and date -->             
            </td>
            <td>
                     This is garbage
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I tried:

```
soup.find_all("td", text = re.compile('(AM|PM)'))[0].get_text().strip()
```

However, the `text` parameter of `find_all` seems to not work for this application: `IndexError: list index out of range`

What do I need to do?

Comment: It works for me in python 3.4 and BeautifulSoup version 4.4.0 for your example html. Can you please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Also works for me in Python 3.5.

Comment: I updated the sample to more specific. I'm trying to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify the tag name at all and let it find the desired *text node*. Works for me:

```
soup.find(text=re.compile('(AM|PM)')).strip()
```